# In GitLab Pipelines is there a way to run a pipeline when a Merge Request is detached?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-api

I am trying to run a pipeline when a merge request in gitlab is detach means that is not a success and is rejected or closed without merging into the branch.
So is it possible to execute it only for CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE=detach as we execute for particular branches?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `only:` with the `variables:` option. I ditn't test this, but please try adding this a job:

```yaml
only:
  variables:
    - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "detach"
```

See the documentation for more details: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyvariablesexceptvariables

Comment: GitLab documentation recommends using `rules` instead of `only`.

Answer (score 1):

```
only:
    - merge_requests
```

Documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html